# node.js filestream to read international characterset(French and German)

Tags: node.js, filestream

In my node.js I read characters from French and German language. As you know some characters doesn't exist in English. So, please help me to read the characters using node.js filestream.

```
fs.createReadStream(sFile,{ encoding: 'latin1' })
tried encoding with  'binary','utf8' nothing works!
```

I want the below string in french to be printed as it is

**Au programme 2019 : plénière composée de témoignages**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 works fine with accentuated characters. The problem is most likely from the file itself.

If your file (`sFile`) is not encoded in UTF-8, you will not get UTF-8 encoded characters.

Most editors (Notepad++, VSCode, etc...) have a feature that lets you convert a file to various charsets.

Comment: how do I encode file to UTF-8, and I am not sure, if it is UTF-8 or utf-8 or utf8

Comment: Default encoding is null, so you should set it to `utf8`, just in case (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options). To encode your source file, you can use an editor, like Nodepad++ or VSCode. I don't know the commands to do it in a terminal.

Comment: Just to make sure, is this syntax correct?  to read/write file stream fs.createReadStream(sFile,{ encoding: 'utf8' })             
fs.createWriteStream(sFile,{ encoding: 'utf8' })                                         Thanks Seblor :)

Comment: This syntax should be correct, yes. The documentation states that the default encoding is already UTF-8 for `createWriteStream`.

Comment: Thank you utf8 works fine also on html it requires <meta> set to utf8